# JComboBox containing data from index positions in a file Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist, combobox

I have a text file as follows which contains data about items of stock. Index position 1 of each line contains the name of the product. I want to be able to take that index position from each line in the file, and display it in a combobox, but I don't know how to do that. I'm trying to use different classes too.

[This is the file as reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Y6H.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first item of each line using [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int)):

```
line.split(",", 3)[1]
```